# android studio - listing files inside AAR bundle - and AAR version management

Tags: android, android-studio

To import an `aar` file, I did a  *(File -> New Module -> Import .aar)* and was able to include local AAR file in Android Studio project and project builds successfully.

Two questions.

1. How to make **android studio list classes in an aar file** as it lists classes in jar files ? ( See the image, listing for `support-annotations-21.0.3.jar` and no listing for `appsdk.aar` file.  )
2. **Version management of local aar file** - While using a local aar file, is there any way, to make sure AAR file imported is of a particular version ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time since the question but we have finally something to show the content:
[archive browser](https://github.com/b3er/idea-archive-browser)